# MongoDb Time series: How to keep last record of the day and delete the rest?

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I store the stock prices in MongoDB Time Series. I am getting the prices every 10 seconds.
I want to keep the prices for 2 months and then delete them but keep the last record of the day as the price for that day.

I can set "expireAfterSeconds" but it deletes everything!
Also We cannot delete record manually from Time Series.

One solution is to use another collection for historical prices but then when I want to get the price to draw the chart I have to run 2 queries. One for Today and last week from first collection and one for last x months from the second collection.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Once per day, run an update like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {
      $and: [
         { daily: { $exists: false } },
         { $expr: { $eq: [{ $dateToString: { date: "$date", format: '%H:%M:%S' } }, '23:59:50'] } },
         { $expr: { $lt: ["$date", { $dateTrunc: { date: "$$NOW", unit: 'day' } }] } }
      ]
   },
   { $set: { daily: true } }
)
```

Or if you want it more generic and more reliable use this update:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         partitionBy: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: 'day' } },
         sortBy: { date: 1 },
         output: {
            lastPrice: { $last: "$date" }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $match: {
         $and: [
            { daily: { $exists: false } },
            { $expr: { $eq: ["$date", "$lastPrice"] } },
            { $expr: { $lt: ["$date", { $dateTrunc: { date: "$$NOW", unit: 'day' } }] } }
         ]
      }
   }
]).toArray().forEach(
   x => {
      db.collection.updateOne(
         { _id: x._id },
         { $set: { daily: true } }
      )
   }
)
```

Then you can create a TTL index like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { date: 1 },
   {
      partialFilterExpression: { daily: { $exists: false } },
      expireAfterSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 62
   }
)
```

Notes:

This TTL index will delete old records after **62 days**, which is slightly more than **2 months**. If you need exactly 2 months, then it would be more complex.

You cannot use

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { daily: { $exists: false } },
   [ ... ]
)
```

when your aggregation pipeline contains `$setWindowFields`, MongoDB throws error `$sort is not allowed to be used within an update` (even if `$sort` is not used in `$setWindowFields`). Thus, you have to update documents in a loop.

Comment: Does time series support TTL indexes?  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/  “You cannot create a TTL index on a time series collection. Similar functionality is provided through automatic removal on time series collections instead”

Comment: Have a look at [Set up Automatic Removal for Time Series Collections (TTL)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-automatic-removal/). However, it looks like you can define a life-time only per aggregation level (e.g. hour) but not for "last value of the day".